# About use keras for multi-label classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I try to train a multi-labels classifier, I used sigmoid units in the output layer and then use "binary_crossentrpy" loss. Current problem is the results of the training and testing were ideal, values of loss and accuracy were great.But when I used model.predict() predicted label, the output don't match the real label value. How to change code to solve it?
The shape of the training set and testing set is (-1, 1, 300, 300), the shape of the target label is (-1, 478), I have 478 in total.
My complete code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam

X = np.load('./data/X_train.npy')
y = np.load('./data/Y_train.npy')
X_train, y_train = X[:2000], y[:2000]
X_test, y_test = X[2000:], y[2000:]

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter=32, nb_row=5, nb_col=5, padding='same', input_shape=(1, 300, 300)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), border_mode='same'))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(478))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Training ------------')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=300, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1)

model.save('model.h5')
```

Could you help me to find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Do do solve this now?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to filter the values based on a threshold?

```
pred = model.predict(x_test)
pred[pred>=0.5] = 1
pred[pred<0.5] = 0
print(pred[0:5])
```